# Applying filters in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table which should show a resultset, filtering the result against the value of a user input:

```
 <input type="search" ng-model="search">

<table>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in data | filter: search">
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="person.name"></td>  
        </tr>
</table>
```

An item of `data` has multiple other attributes, e.g `person.id`

Now i want to apply a filter to my ng-repeat directive, which allows me to show only those results, which contain `person.name == searchterm`.

I have read through the documentation and watched some videos. Because of that, i understood how to apply a filter to an expression.

However, i would like to know how i could apply both, a filter on my searchterm **and** attribute `person.name`

Comment: The official angular documentation has an example that does exactly that: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

Comment: @JBNizet, thank you. However, i meant to combine both values into one single input element

Comment: what does combine both values mean?  Need to explain criteria a lot better

Comment: instead of `:strict` in the example filter, hardcode `:true`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS filter only on certain objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814283/angularjs-filter-only-on-certain-objects)