# Strange table search results with Angularjs Filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-filter, servicenow

Our team has built an HTML table with a search input at the top:

```
<input placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchTable">
```

In our ng-repeat, we have the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data.list | filter:searchTable track by item.sys_id">
```

This works for the most part, but after extensive testing, we noticed some strange results.  Below is what the table returned after we searched for "88":

[image]

The above SSNs are all fake, but you can see a number of entries that came back that did not have "88" in any of the columns.  In fact all of them don't even have a single 8.  Are we anything incorrect here?  Any suggestions on how to fix this bug?  Thanks!

Comment: Is there any data not shown in your table that would match what is being filtered?

Comment: no there aren't

Comment: Can you log one the objects for us to see?

Comment: hey @tbone849, I think i know what's going on, but unsure how to fix it.  The Employee Name column is a reference field to a User table.  Each User entry has a unique id and for each of the outliers outlined in red above, all of their unique id's (sys_id's) contain "88".  Not sure why the search would be able to search beyond the column display values and unsure of how to prevent it from doing so.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The filter doesn’t care what is displayed on the table. It will filter all the data that exists on the object.

Comment: A custom filter could fix this issue though

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13821640/5781575